# Is there a command for going back a number of steps in a directory, without using cd?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, terminal

I'm constantly going 'cd ../../../../'. Is there a command/alias that could let me go 'cmd 4' and I'd be taken back 4 directories?

Comment: `ls`? Surely you mean `cd`?

Comment: Yeah I do, I just wrote this in a rush ;) Editing it now.

Comment: Wiil this do?: `alias cmd5 = "cd ../../../../../"`

Comment: Well, I suppose I could write them out for 1 to 10 or so, but it'd be nice to have a clever way of doing it. That doesn't really sit right with me. Will do that if no other solution emerges, though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Put this in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
cdup() {
  levels=${1-1}
  while ((levels--)); do
    cd ..
  done
}
```

(The name `cdup` comes from the corresponding FTP command, just FYI.)

Comment: Thanks for the response, went with the jleedev's answer due to it being 1 line shorter and I couldn't make up my mind who's to choose! Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Muu: Both answers will work, but mine will work for many, many levels, and @jleedev's will only work for a small handful (whatever the stack limit is). ;-) (I'm sure you'll never hit the limit either way, but mine is more general, is what I'm trying to get at. :-))

Comment: Fair point, I've awarded you the answer then. Sorry jleedev - though most likely I'll continue using your solution as I'll forget to change it :)

Answer (score 11):

I was taught to use 'pushd' and 'popd' for such circumstances.

For example, type 'pushd .' and then 'cd /home'. Now type 'popd' and you will be back to where you started.

'pushd'/'popd' is a stack, you can push as many directories on there as you like, but it is last on, first off when you popd.

Comment: Hm, nice. Not heard of that. Doesn't quite fit what I was looking for, but will use that too. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

Sure, why not:

```
up() {
    [ $# = 0 ] && cd .. && return
    [ $1 = 0 ] && return
    cd .. && up $(($1 - 1))
}
```

Comment: Bash isn't tail-recursive, right? You might stack overflow if you do `up 500`. :-)

Comment: If your directories are nested that deeply, you have my sympathies.

Comment: Used this. Beat Chris by 1 line ;)

Comment: @Muu: I didn't know this question was a code golf! ;-) BTW, come join us! http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Wasn't planning it to be, but when presented with two bits of code that seem to work as well as each other - you need some kind of criteria! :)

Comment: @Muu Please remember that recursion is *not* the proper way to write shell scripts in general.

Answer (score 4):

Quick and dirty:

```
cmd () { dir=.; for i in $(seq 1 $1); do dir=$dir/..; done; pushd $dir; }
```

Formulated to only change directory once.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative way:

```
function cdup
{
    cd $(for ((i=0 ; i<$1 ;i++)); do printf "../" ; done)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into using `pushd` and `popd` to set location markers and and get back there easily from whatever directory you changed to.

You could also set a variable with the name of a directory you use a lot, then CD there:

```
MYPROJ=~/projects/name/src
cd $MYPROJ
proj1='cd $MYPROJ'
```

Answer (score 1):

I use [autojump](https://github.com/joelthelion/autojump/wiki) which allow me to type :

```
j h
>> /home/cjulien
j et
>> /etc
```

it can learn from your habits and is very light (and addictive ;) )

Answer (score 1):

Build the path using `printf` then `cd` to it:

```
cdup() {
    local path
    printf -v path '%*s' "${1:-1}"
    cd "${path// /../}"
}
```

Use as:

```
cdup 4 # to go up four directories
cdup 1 # to explicitly go up one directory
cdup   # to implicitly go up one
```

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts that might be of use to you:

1. cd -
   change back to the last directory you were in. I use this all the time to get from deep down in my code tree back to the root of it... though that only works if you cd'd down into it in one change.
2. cdd old new
   this was a script function I had written in the past that I used for moving around between similar trees. Basically it took two arguments and did a regexp on your path, great for moving around between branches and such. For example if you were in ~/bzr/web/trunk/path/to/feature and needed to get to ~/bzr/web/feature-branch/path/to/feature then you would do `cdd trunk feature-branch`. The implementation I had was in an archaic shell language on AIX, but it was pretty trivial, so should be easy to implement in shell of choice if you need it. For us it was very useful because the structure looked like: .../{product}/{version}/{release}/{src,bld,dbg,pkg,tst}/{component}/... so moving around in that tree got insane pretty quick.